# Position a body in cannon.js relative to local rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I have a body in cannon.js that has a quaternion rotation applied to it. I want to move it 100 units along a vector relative to it's local rotation.

Eg

```
let body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
body.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,1),(2*Math.PI)/6);
body.position.set(0,0,100); //this is wrong
```

Using `body.position.set(x, y, z);` moves the body relative to the world rather than the local rotation. I think I need to add a vector after applying the quaternion to it, but the docs for cannon.js aren't particularly helpful so I've not been able to work out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Quaternion#vmult](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Quaternion.html#method_vmult) method to rotate a vector and [Vec3#add](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Vec3.html#method_vadd) to add the result to the position.

```
let body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
body.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,1),(2*Math.PI)/6);
let relativeVector = new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,100);

// Use quaternion to rotate the relative vector, store result in same vector
body.quaternion.vmult(relativeVector, relativeVector);

// Add position and relative vector, store in body.position
body.position.vadd(relativeVector, body.position);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758653/cannonjs-want-to-rotate-lot-of-bodies-like-one-body Any suggest