# Move Cannon.JS Body Toward Dynamic Position?

Tags: cannon.js

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this.
What I'm trying to do, is move a physics body, by the means of velocity, toward another body, until it reaches and hits said body. (Think AI following a player)

One solution is the following:

```
body.velocity.x = target.position.x-body.position.x;
body.velocity.z = target.position.z-body.position.z;
```

This has issues, though. One being that the velocity is higher depending on the distance between the two bodies. I would prefer a fixed speed. Another way would be to use the following example: [Position a body in cannon.js relative to local rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810707/position-a-body-in-cannon-js-relative-to-local-rotation)

But in this case, I need a way of rotating the quaternion, so it faces the target position, this with only knowing the 2 positions of the bodies.

So the question is, how do I calculate the velocity OR direction of the body, so that it can follow and collide with the target body, by using a fixed speed/velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a fixed speed, `.normalize()` your velocity vector and then scale (`.mult()`) the result by the speed you want. The result will be a vector that always has the length you want.

To get a quaternion that makes your body face in a certain direction, you can use `Quaternion.setFromVectors(u,v)`. This method creates a quaternion which will rotate `u` so it points in the same direction as `v`. If you set `u` to your forward vector and `v` to the direction you want the body to look, you will get the correct "look at" behavior. Note that the "forward" vector might be different for your game.

```
// Compute direction to target
var direction = new CANNON.Vec3();
target.position.vsub(body.position, direction);
direction.y = 0;
direction.normalize();

// Get the rotation between the forward vector and the direction vector
var forward = new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,1);
body.quaternion.setFromVectors(forward, direction);

// Multiply direction by 10 and store in body.velocity
var fixedSpeed = 10;
direction.mult(fixedSpeed,body.velocity);
```